# C++ Reverse order of Input and Print it out as Char*

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have to reverse the order of the input (which the user types in), and then print out that reversed order with the variable `ret` that I have. If you go to line 33 in my code you will see `cout << "output : " << ret << endl;`. This is an assignment so unfortunately I have to use `ret` otherwise I would just print it out using `int`. I tried reversing the order with `int` data type variables and then converting them to `char*` to match the `ret` data type. Then I made them equal to each other in an attempt to print using `ret` as you can see in line 32 where I wrote `ret = char_type;`. However, that leads me to the error *Makefile:6: recipe for target 'cpp_run' failed.* I am new to C++ and programming in general so I would like some help fixing this code.

**This is my code:**

````
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char* reserve_num_from_int_to_char(int num){
    
    char* output = new char[100];
    
    
    
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    int input, reversednumber = 0, remainder;
    cout << "input : " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    char* ret = reserve_num_from_int_to_char(input);
    
    while(input != 0) {
        remainder = input%10;
        reversednumber = reversednumber*10 + remainder;
        input /= 10;
    }
    
    stringstream strs;
    strs << reversednumber;
    string temp_str = strs.str();
    char* char_type = (char*)temp_str.c_str();
    ret = char_type;
    cout << "output : " << ret << endl;
    
    delete[] ret;
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea about going over the digits of the inputted number.

The missing part is converting them to the `char`s that represent those digits. Luckily, all the characters representing digits are sequential, so they can all be represented as the offset of that digit from the character `'0'`:

```c
// Function definition given by the instruction
char* reserve_num_from_int_to_char(int num) {
    // Note: You're allocating the array using new here, 
    // so you'll have to delete it after you're done using the result
    char* output = new char[100];
    
    int i = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        // Get the digit
        int digit = num % 10;
    
        // convert it to a character
        output[i] = '0' + digit;
        ++i;

        // Move on to the next digit
        num /= 10;
    }

    // Don't forget the terminating '\0' to make it a valid c-string:
    output[i] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: If the function is modified to accept a pointer to a `char` array and the length of the `char` array, you can eliminate the need for dynamic allocation in most cases. The user will make a local array, call `reserve_num_from_int_to_char` (`reverse_num_from_int_to_char`?), and then let the array go out of scope when they're done with it.

Comment: @user4581301 True 'dat. That would indeed be a cleaner design, but I wasn't sure if modifying the function's signature was allowed or not

Comment: No clue either. It's just an option for the asker or those who follow to pursue.